# Download source packages from pypi without installing build dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I would like to download the source version of a package in PyPI and its dependencies. It seems that using `pip3 download --no-binary :all: <package>` installs the build dependencies before downloading. This can be very time consuming, because the build dependencies sometimes require a lot of building, and can fail if you do not have the tools required to build the dependencies.

```
 pip3 download --no-binary :all: scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.9.3.tar.gz (42.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42.1 MB 394 kB/s            
  Installing build dependencies ...
```

This takes a long time and eventually fails because one of the build dependencies fails to build. Is it possible to just download the source packages *without* building anything?

I have also tried the `--no-deps` option (although I *do* want the dependencies). It still tries to install and build the build dependencies.

Comment: That's a good question – the issue is that figuring out the runtime dependencies requires installing build dependencies, and scipy seems to require `meson-python`, which... yeah.

Comment: I'd almost raise this as an issue over at https://github.com/pypa/pip...